# Глючит эмулятор андроид

Tags: android-studio

С эклипсом всё работало нормально.
удалил эклипс (естественно засейвив), и скачал android studio 2.0 надеясь, что её довели до ума. Но не тут то было.
Мало того, что она тормозит пуще прежней, но эмулятор отображается вот так:
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461317109/bb6c1a94/12399996.jpg
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461317158/5d793f50/12400002.jpg
Наверное ненужно говорить, что без бубна и ручного прописывания переменных среды, эмулятор тупо не запускается. Но и после запуска не хочет толком работать.
Драйверы видео - не предлагать.(играю в Fallout4 на этой машинке)
Внимание вопрос: что делать для нормального отображения эмулятора?

Comment: Эмуляторы от гугла - боль. Апдейты гугла - всегда баги. Так что используйте Genymotion и не спешите обновлять гугловые продукты.

Comment: Спасибо! Эмулятор Genymotion действительно несколько быстрее дефолтного, и главное не выдаёт тех фортелей, что на скринах. Но сама среда Android Studio медленная до умопомрачения.

Comment: Ну, лично я так и вообще ни разу не сумел гугловый эмулятор запустить ни на одной версии студии) И обновлять студию не буду до, как минимум, версии 2.1 ибо боюсь того, что они там накодили - уж очень хорошо знаком с тем кол-вом багов, кои они всё время во все крупные апдейты пихают. Так что я бы на вашем месте откатился бы на 1.5. А тормознутость можно и потерпеть - всё ж во всём остальном студия хороша и альтернатив нема.

Comment: хех... я даже пару приложений написал с дефолтным эмулятором причём одно из них в линуксе. Остальные писал с реальными устройствами. Что касается откатов, то думаю нужно комп помощнее брать. i5-й пенёк уже вчерашний день